# Cucmber testing a button press and having no success updating page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, button, cucumber, capybara

I am running cucmber test on my rails app. I am trying to log in to a page using a button press. In the test I walk through the login steps and press the button and then check the text to see if it matches what should be on th epage after the button press. I am not having any luck

The .html code looks like

```
<% provide(:title, "Log in") %>
<h1>Log in</h1>

<h2>Note: authentication currently supports both a TAMU NetID or the use of CAS.</h2>
<h2>To access the CAS authentication system, click <%= link_to "here", new_member_session_path %></h2> <br />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    <%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :netid %>
      <%= f.text_field :username, class: 'form-control' %>

      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>

  </div>
</div>
```

My test looks like

```
    Given I am logged in as an admin user
    And I should see "admin@member.com"
    And I should see "Test Member"
    And I should see "Create Member"
    And I should see "Create Committee"
```

With this step in my webstep files

```
Given(/^I am logged in as an admin user$/) do    
visit '/sessions/new'
page.should have_content('Log in')
page.should have_content('Note: authentication currently supports both a TAMU NetID or the use of CAS.')
page.should have_content('To access the CAS authentication system, click here')
fill_in 'session_username' , :with => 'admin'
click_button 'Log in'
expect(page).to have_content 'Admin Member'
```

end

But I keep getting this error

```
expected to find text "Admin Member" in "MembershipHub\nHome About Help Login\nNo member found with that NetID\nLog in\nNote: authentication currently supports both a TAMU NetID or the use of CAS.\nTo access the CAS authentication system, click here\nNetid\nAbout Help Members SEC Main Site RegistrationHub FinanceHub (Alpha)" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:140:in `/^(?:|I )should see "([^"]*)"$/'
      features/IterationTwo_adminMember_testing.feature:6:in `Then I should see "Admin Member"'
```

Which the text it is showing is actually on the login page. I am not sure why I cannot see the page following the press of the log in button.

Comment: Where are you creating the “admin” user? You can see from the page text that it’s reporting a “No member found with that NetID” error.

Comment: I guess I missed that in the error. The weird thing is, when I run the rails server locally, I am able to login as this admin user. I do not know why it does not work here. I will make an edit to something I just tried.

Comment: Dev mode (you running the server) and test mode (Capybara running the server) use different databases - you need to setup all the records needed for each test either using fixtures or a factory library like factory_bot

Comment: How would you do it using fixtures?

Comment: Probably https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Fixtures - not 100% sure though, I haven’t used fixtures in quite some time

Comment: Thank you! there is no way to copy my development database over to my test database?

Comment: You don’t want to do that - you want the tests to be isolated from each other and run in a known state. You probably need to read up on testing a bit more.

Comment: okay thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the issue here is that the user being logged in as doesn't exists because  the data required for the test hasn't been set up prior to running the test. This data needs to be initialized in the test database (generally done using Rails fixtures or a factory tool like [factory_bot](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_bot)).